# Initializing "const std::string" from "std::istringstream"

Tags: c++, constants, stdstring, const-correctness, istringstream

I'm trying to parse a file which is in `Key<whitespace>Value` format. I'm reading the file lines in an `std::istringstream` object, and I'm extracting a `Key` string from it. I want to avoid accidentally changing the value of this `Key` string by making it `const`.

My best attempt was initializing a temporary `VariableKey` object, and then making a constant one out of it.

```
std::ifstream FileStream(FileLocation);
std::string FileLine;
while (std::getline(FileStream, FileLine))
{
    std::istringstream iss(FileLine);
    std::string VariableKey;
    iss >> VariableKey;
    const std::string Key(std::move(VariableKey));

    // ...
    // A very long and complex parsing algorithm
    // which uses `Key` in a lot of places.
    // ...
}
```

How do I directly initialize a constant `Key` string object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's arguably better to separate file I/O from processing, and instead of creating a `const` `Key` inside the same function - call a line-processing function that takes a `const std::string& key` parameter.

That said, if you want to continue with your current model, you can simply use:

```
const std::string& Key = VariableKey;
```

There's no need to copy or move anything anywhere.  Only `const` `std::string` members functions will be accessible via `Key`.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the "scratch" variable by extracting the input into a function:

```
std::string get_string(std::istream& is) 
{
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
    return s;
}

// ...

while (std::getline(FileStream, FileLine))
{
    std::istringstream iss(FileLine);
    const std::string& Key = get_string(iss);

// ...
```

(Binding the function's result to a const reference extends its lifetime.)